# Change post count on tag/terms pages to 10

Tags: functions, tags, terms

I have modified my search results page with a function to change the search results count to 10. How can I do the same thing, but for the tag/terms pages? Do I edit the function for search results to include the tag page, or add a whole new function? Here is the function I am using for the search results page:

```
function change_wp_search_size($query) {
if ( $query->is_search ) // Make sure it is a search page
    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10; // Change 10 to the number of posts you would like to show

return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size'); // Hook our custom function onto the request filter
```

I found this function, but it did not change the post count for me:

```
function main_query_mods( $query ) {
// check http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags to play with other queries
if(!$query->is_main_query()) {
    return;
}
if(is_tag()) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page',10);
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'main_query_mods' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there my friend. Just check with `$query->is_tag()` rather than only `is_tag()`. So your updated code will be-

```
function main_query_mods( $query ) {
    // check http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags to play with other queries
    if(!$query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }
    if($query->is_tag()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page',10);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'main_query_mods' );
```

Comment: hmmm I added that function and now website is showing only 5 posts on both the search results and the tags pages. Does this maybe mean the query is being called somewhere else that is changing it?

Comment: May be. Cause I've tested it twice it worked perfectly in my system. @EmilyG